# Which one of the words should the preposition be considered with?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Small huts have been built to accommodate visitors **to** the island.

The question is that, which one of the words does the preposition ***to*** relate to?
is it *accomodate visitors **to** the island* or separately, *visitors **to** the island*

Comment: The PP "to the island" is modifying the noun "visitors". It identifies which visitors are being accommodated. The NP "the island" is complement of "to".

Comment: *does...should* is ungrammatical.  "Which one of the words should the preposition be considered with?"

Comment: **to** refers to **the island**.

Comment: @BillJ so, so there's no any expression like *to accommodate someone **to** somewhere* right?

Comment: but **visitors to the island** itself is the separate expression ? did I get it right?

Comment: "To the island", which is headed by "to", is a dependent (a modifier)of "visitors".  "Accommodate visitors to the island" is a verb phrase, headed by "accommodate", which has "visitors to the island" as complement.

Comment: please excuse my belabour since what I've learned so far from the dictionary definitions, in the sense of lodging , *to accommodate someone* is the sole construction without any *to*  following it. So I got a bit confused when  I read  - "Accommodate visitors to the island" is the wholly verb phrase".

Comment: *to accommodate someone **in/on/at** somewhere* is the common prepositions that we usually come across, but when it comes to ***to***, I think I'll need some broad explanation regarding its usage patterns.

Comment: Please, include more context and do a research. Is it an exam question?

Answer (score 1):

The second instance of the word 'to' relates to the island. You're correct that 'visitors to the island' is a separate expression. To make it clear, think about it in two separate sentences:

> Small huts have been built to accommodate visitors.

and

> The visitors are visitors to the island.

The verb is not 'to accommodate to'. It is 'to accommodate', specifically

> to accommodate visitors

If you want to understand the meaning of 'accommodate' here using one of the prepositions you've identified as commonly used with 'accommodate', think of it this way

> to accommodate visitors to the island in small huts